# django models hierarchy question: related attributes of a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

As a fresh coder, I seriously have problems to build my models relations.

Please check these two cases, How can I set current_reading_pages on my Scenario2?

```
from django.db import models

# Scenario1: Users can record their reading progress of a book.

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class User(models.Model):
    current_reading_book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_reading_page = models.IntegerField()
```

Result1: No problems about database, but Users can records their progress of only one book.

Other scenario, which I want to build:

```
from django.db import models

# Scenario2: Users can record their reading progress of multiple books.    

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class User(models.Model):
    current_reading_books = models.ManyToManyField('Book')
    # current_reading_pages = ???
```

I want to save all progress of current books, for example,
User A is reading 3 books, book1 till page 100, book2 till page 10, book3 till page 0.

And I found 'through' parameter in django ManyToManyField,
My codes become like below but it does not work as I expected.

```
from django.db import models

# Scenario3: Using through parameter in ManyToManyField  

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class User(models.Model):
    current_reading_books = models.ManyToManyField('Book', through='ReadingBook')

class ReadingBook(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_reading_page = models.IntegerField()
```

ERRORS:
test_model.ReadingBook: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'test_model.User.current_reading_books', but it does not have a foreign key to 'User' or 'Book'.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that first scenario is easy to realize.
just add user attribute into the custom class UserBook
for example

```
class UserBooks(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_page = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

if user wanna check his progress, in **views.py** you can just filter by **books = UserBooks.objects.filter(user=request.user)**